# Sql server Job triggered while server is down

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL server job that triggered three times in the week on specific time.
what is the server is off. will it waits until the agent comes up and start the job that times over or will neglect those??

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Job agent depends on SQL Server being up and running.
So if either of the above is down the job scheduler will not start the job. The Job Agent will not fire Jobs that have missed their schedulres.
Some info on how to check if the job has been run: [SQL Server - TSQL to Detect missed Agent jobs due to overrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636505/sql-server-tsql-to-detect-missed-agent-jobs-due-to-overrun)